# Using a Windows-based Mercurial repository in a NTFS drive from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, hg

I have a dual-boot, Windows/Linux machine.
There, I have a mercurial repository in the NTFS data partition, which was cloned using Windows' TortoiseHg. It's also usually pushed/pulled through Windows.

When I'm working under Linux, the repo doesn't work, seemingly because of character encoding. The `--encoding` parameter is also failing:

[image: --encoding doesn't seem to help]

Is there any way around this?